# How can we create object of interface in java?

Tags: java, interface

How is this code working i m totally puzzled....

```
package com.servletpack.examples;

interface check {
    public void message();
}
public class Interface {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            check t = new check() {//how????????????????
                public void message() {
                    System.out.println("Method defined in the interface");
                }
            };
            t.message();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try [googling](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=How+can+we+create+object+of+interface+in+java%3F&rlz=1C1CHEU_iwIL474IL474&oq=How+can+we+create+object+of+interface+in+java%3F&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l2j0l3.802j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) it?

Comment: Did you try to google things and to see JAVA fundamentals? refere to this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With that syntax, you create an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), which is perfectly legal.

Internally, anonymous classes are compiled to a class of their own, called `EnclosingClass$n` where the enclosing class' name precedes the `$` sign. and `n` increases for each additional anonymous class.  This means that the following class is being created:

```
class Interface$1 implements check {
     public void message() {
         System.out.println("Method defined in the interface");
     }
}
```

Then, the code in `main` compiles to internally use the newly-defined anonymous class:

```
check t = new Interface$1();
t.message();
```

Comment: What if Interface$1 is an abstract class?

Comment: @RamaKrishna Anonymous classes cannot be abstract. If the interface `check` was instead an abstract class, it's anonymous implementation would similarly be named `Interface$1`.

Comment: Great answer, @FThompson ! Solved my doubt entirely.

Answer (score 9):

It is anonymous class. Your **check** class is an interface. Anonymous class defines an implementation of given interface on the fly. So it saves you from creating a seperate class for Interface's implementation. This approach is only useful when you know you will never require this implementation any where else in the code.

Hope this explanation helps !!

Answer (score 6):

You are creating an instance (on the fly) of [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) that implements the interface check.

Answer (score 3):

Your interface reference can hold the object of the implementing class. You are implementing an anonymous class and assigning it to the reference of interface, which is absolutely legal in JAVA.