# Why do listeners sometimes get registered to "this" and sometimes to an anonymous class?

Tags: java, android, interface

When I read sample Android code that registers listeners, sometimes I see:

```
someService.registerListener(this);
```

In that case the current class is declared as `implements SomeListener` and overrides the 1 or more methods declared in the `SomeListener` interface, i.e. later in the current class, they would declare:

```
@Override
public void someInterfaceMethod() {
    ...
}
```

Other times I see:

```
someService.registerListener(new SomeListener() {
    @Override
    public void someInterfaceMethod() {
        ...
    });
```

Is there a reason to prefer one method over the other?

Comment: `this` is often used in short example code, for brevity.  I'd use an inner class or an entirely separate class in production code.  (The reason is you typically don't want to expose unnecessary interfaces, and `this` requires one on the outer class.)

Comment: I was told once that having multiple OnClickListener, for example, becomes unnecessary bloat and you can simply use an if statement and one listener to check which view you have clicked.

Comment: I get that, but isn't the "if" statement just moving the bloat from one place to the other?  Also perhaps there is some performance penalty because you have to execute the "if" on every click

Answer (score 1):

There is no prefered way to choose from the two options, the method only wants a class that conforms to the interface contract(implements all it's methods).

I use `this` when I'm trying not to have too many anonyoumous classes, but one that combines them all

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn1:
            doSomething;
            break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            doSomethingElse();
            break;
    }
}
```

I also can have the same functionality without using the outer class by definning some variable outside the function and assign it to all of my Methods.

```
private View.OnClickLisetner myClickListener = new View.OnClickListsner() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn1:
                doSomething;
                break;
            case R.id.btn2:
                doSomethingElse();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your own class is implementing the interface, so the compiler will find the overridden methods inside your class contract, you're referring this as the class that will modify the behavior of those methods.

Comment: I am not asking for an explanation of what's going on... I'm asking why to prefer one way over the other

Answer (score 0):

As earlier mentioned by @Ahmed it is nice explaination but i will go little deeper.

When you implement interface for some listener compiler will just register that class as listener for that kind of event.  but when you directly pass interface like

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
```

Or like this

```
private View.OnClickLisetner myClickListener = new View.OnClickListsner() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn1:
                doSomething;
                break;
            case R.id.btn2:
                doSomethingElse();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

compiler will create anonymous class for you and then register that subclass as event listener for event. [More about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880494/how-can-we-create-object-of-interface-in-java)

Now for usage 
its up to you developer how you implement it. in my opinion when you want that event (any event like click or touch) more than 2 times you should implement interface and over ride methods so it won't create too many internal (anonymous) classes at runtime.