# Creating a path object when Path is an interface?

Tags: java, interface, path

I don't understand how a Path object can be created if the Path class is an interface itself.

```
Path path = Paths.get("...");
```

I'm having a real struggle, and I'm also a beginner, so please help out!

Comment: Please read upcasting  and downcasting in java first

Comment: What is this not doing?  Are you getting an error when you run the code?

Comment: You can look at these answers: [This appears to create an object from an interface; how does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947708/this-appears-to-create-an-object-from-an-interface-how-does-it-work) [How can we create object of interface in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880494/how-can-we-create-object-of-interface-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that the underlying code is something like this:

```
interface Path {}
class PathImpl implements Path {
  String path;
  PathImpl(String path) { this.path = path; }
}
class Paths {
  static Path get(String path) { return new PathImpl(path); }
}
```

So If you call `Paths.get("abc")` with my example, you will receive a `new PathImpl("abc")` which implements the `Path` interface.

Comment: Now this piece of code brings me to another question. 
The get() method in Paths returns a Path value, but it's an interface?
I'm kinda stupid, sorry about that

Comment: The get method returns a PathImpl which *is a* Path. If that concept is unclear you should probably [read about inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Comment: Okay, I understood what you said, just one more thing. In the end, the 'path' variable in my code above, is it still a PathImpl type of a variable, just upcasted as a Path?

Comment: yes exactly. You could write: `Path p = Paths.get("abc"); if (p instanceof PathImpl) PathImpl pi = (PathImpl) p;`. It would run fine.

Answer (score 1):

An interface defines a type in Java. If you get an object that has type `Path` you and the compiler will know the methods that may be called. You will additionally know what you may expect the methods to do. `Paths.get` returns an instance of a class that implements the interface `Path`.

You don't know the implementing class and you should not have to know it so that your code does not rely on implementation details. Interfaces provide the possibility to implement "loose coupling". You can use an interface and write code that calls it's methods even if there is still no implementation (useful especially for a top-down-approach). Interfaces enable you to have multiple implementations of an interface which specifies the common behaviour that all implementations have to implement. `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` are examples of multiple classes implementing the interface `List`. This is called polymorphism. Many standards include interfaces to specify a behavior. This allows multiple implementations of the stabdard to exist.

Comment: Okay, but I'm confused about one thing. When the `Paths.get` returns an object from class that implements the interface 'Path', and it's assigned to my variable 'Path path', is 'path' still an object from 'PathImplClass'?

Comment: Yes, it is. path instanceof PathImplClass returns true. So, you can downcast, but this is usually something that one wants to avoid because it breaks the loose coupling. PathImplClass still makes a difference even if you don't do a downcast because it's actual methods are called. Imagine you are in a restaurant. You can order something without knowing the actual cook that will process your order, but you know that he/she has a method order(Meal). Every cook cooks his/her own way, but each of them prepares your meal.

Answer (score 0):

[assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829571/assylias) said that it returns a PathImpl which *is a* Path. If you're confused about the meaning of "is a", read about [inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) in java.