# What does Naming.lookup() do?

Tags: java, casting, rmi

I have been going through a very simple example to set up a Remote Method Invocation application and while going through the client side code I am not able to understand one code as shown below. Definitely, gaps in my knowledge because I though an interface cannot have objects [unless you use Anonymous Inner Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880494/how-can-we-create-object-of-interface-in-java). So in the code below how did we creat an object of Remote Interface. It seems some sort of type-casting to me if I had to guess.

```
import java.rmi.*; 
public class HelloClient { 
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
  try { 
    if (args.length < 0) { 
      System.err.println("usage: java HelloClient string …\n"); 
      System.exit(1); 
    } 
HelloInterface hello = (HelloInterface)Naming.lookup("//localhost/Hello");
```

This last line is what I am not able to understand what exactly is happening here with (HelloInterface) part?

Comment: There is no J2EE here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
HelloInterface hello = (HelloInterface)Naming.lookup("//localhost/Hello");
```

- This `Naming.lookup()` call inspects the RMI Registry running in the localhost for a binding under the name "Hello".
- It returns an Object that has to be cast to whatever remote interface you're expecting it to be.
- You can then use that object to call the remote methods defined in the interface.

> I thought an interface cannot have objects unless you use Anonymous Inner Class.

I have no idea what you're talking about here. Any class can implement an interface. This is rather basic.

> So in the code below how did we create an object of Remote Interface

We didn't. We got it as a return value from the Registry, where it was put by the server.

> It seems some sort of type-casting to me if I had to guess.

No need to guess. That's exactly what it is. There is only one 'sort' of typecasting, and this is how you write it. This is also rather basic.

Comment: But regarding this :
I have no idea what you're talking about here. Any class can implement an interface. This is rather basic.                                                                                     I meant that interfaces do not have direct objects , only through classes.

Comment: That's exactly what I said. I don't understand why you think this is a problem. It isn't.. There are plenty of methods in the JDK that return interface types, not just in RMI, and conceal the actual object class from you.

Answer (score 0):

HelloInterface hello = (HelloInterface)Naming.lookup("//localhost/Hello");

**What is this mean ?**

It is basically looking for an object in the server object pool registered with a name //localhost/Hello. this is called JNDI name

Depending on the type of server, this can be configured within the server configuration file.

Comment: The name is "Hello", and there is no JNDI here.

Comment: Now you've merely misquoted the OP's source code. You seem to be just guessing here.

Comment: The statement about a 'server configuration file' is incorrect as well. There is no such thing in RMI.