# What's syntax object : interface in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm newbie in `Kotlin` and `Android`.

I confused when see syntax when use `TextWatcher` like this:

```
editTextSample.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                                   count: Int, after: Int) {
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                               before: Int, count: Int) {
        txtView1.setText("Text in EditText : "+s)
    }
})
```

Can you explain it for me. Thank you

Comment: It's basically Kotlin's equivalent to Java's anonymous class: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html

Answer (score 1):

`EditText` class  extends `TextView` class which contains a method called `addTextChangedListener()`.

Here you are creating the object of `EditText` class and calling that method. Where you need to pass the object of `TextWatcher` interface as argument.

[Hold on.. but we can not create the object of interface. So here we are
                using concept of anonymous class for that, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16880512/5705721) ].

and as the interface contains three methods we have to override them all. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Notation `object : TextWatcher` is just creating an anonymous class here. It's just kotlin way of creating it. Kotlin gives you more methods to implement TextWatchers.

You can import androidx.core:core-ktx dependency which provides a lot of nice features. One of them is extensions for textwatchers. With using this you can simplify your code to:

```
        editTExt.doOnTextChanged { text, start, count, after -> 
            //Do something here
        }
```